# Creating links with tables names that show table information when clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a page that shows the name of multiple mysql tables and creates a link for each one. When a user clicks a link, he's taken to a page that shows him the table contents.

For example:

Link with table name.

```
<a href="contents.php">Table name</a>
```

The user clicks the link and is taken to the page contents.php. That page prints the table contents.

For example if I have a table with Name and Age columns and John and 24 inserted in the columns, the page would print John and 24.

I appreciate if anybody can help me.

Comment: That's nice that you're trying. Good for you. But you didn't ask any question.

Comment: @MightyPork My question is if this is possible and how would one do it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There is SQL command `SHOW TABLES` and other similar things to do it.

Comment: @POP86 your question not so clear but does <a href='contents.php?table=user'>User</a> work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one...

```
$result = mysql_query("show tables"); // run the query and assign the result to $result
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result
      echo "<a href=\"content.php?tableName=".$table[0]."\" >".$table[0] . "</a><BR>";      // print the table that was returned on that row.
}
```

content.php...

```
if(isset($_GET["tableName"]))
{
$select="select *from ".$_GET["tableName"];
$result=mysql_query($select);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row["name"];
echo $row["age"];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is almost working, but there's something wrong with echo `<a href=\"content.php?tableName=".$table[0]."\" >$table[0] ."</a><BR>";`. I think it should be `echo "<a href='content.php?tableName='".$table[0]."'\'" >$table[0]"'</a>'";` but I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'</a>'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: sorry, there is small error please replace with it `  echo "<a href=\"content.php?tableName=".$table[0]."\" >".$table[0] . "</a><BR>";  ` i also going to update above thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would be way easier to do this with a GET request rather than a post request.

```
<a href="contents.php?tableName=actual_table_name">Table name</a>
```

Then in your contents.php file:

```
<?php 
$tablename = $_GET["tableName"] 

/* all your queries that you want to do with tablename goes here */

?>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have multiple tables and I have no idea how to show their names and create a link for each one automatically.